# Javascript get the highest number only if it is unique

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can get the max number from an array but it will also return the max number if it is the same as another number in the array. I want to get the number, or otherwise check if the number is actually higher than the others in the array.

```
const check = Math.max(...[r, g, b]);
let colcheck = false;
if (check === r && colour === 'r' && r > g && r > b) colcheck = true;
else if (check === g && colour === 'g' && g > r && g > b) colcheck = true;
else if (check === b && colour === 'b' && b > r && b > g) colcheck = true;
```

This works but seems a bit of a mess to me and probably isn't the most optimised way of doing it. So with RGB values as 1,1,0 `colcheck` would be false with `colour` as 'r' or 'g' since it is not higher than the others. But with RGB values as 20,97,6 `colcheck` would be true with `colour` as 'g' but `false` with other values.

Comment: Please provide a valid expected output. Do you just want a number if there is a unique max value? *"But with RGB values as 20,97,6 `colcheck` would be true with `colour` as 'g' but `false` with other values."*  Do you need booleans for each RGB values? What is `colour` here?

Comment: @adiga Not sure what you mean, booleans for the RGB values? My two example RGB values are not booleans. "Do you just want a number if there is a unique max value?" Yes as in the title, get the highest number itself.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the array will always consist of 3 values, we can return the lowest value of the three if 2 of the values are the same:

```js
let r = 10;
let g = 10;
let b = 5;
const rgb = [r, g, b];
const check = rgb.filter(e => e === Math.max(...rgb)).length === 1 ? Math.max(...rgb) : Math.min(...rgb);

console.log(check); // 5
```

Comment: But isn't the title to return the HIGHEST number and not the lowest?

Comment: @Hasen If the two highest numbers are the same the third and smallest number is the unique maximum by default. If the highest number is also the highest unique number this will return exactly that.

Comment: Right, Hasen, but you also mentioned you only want it if it's unique. Will the array ever contain more than 3 values?

Comment: It will always have three RGB values. The main thing is to get the highest number, and not the lowest. That's literally the opposite.

Comment: But you only want the highest value if it's unique, right? If the highest value is not unique, 2 out of 3 are the highest, there's literally only 1 value left, which coincidentally is the lowest.

Comment: So if it's 11,10,5 it will return 11 in the console log?

Comment: Correct. It will only return the "lowest" when the other 2 are the same. There are no other numbers left over, and will automatically be the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with `reduce()` like this:

```
const colnam="rgb-";
const primcol=c=>{var prim=0;
    c.reduce((mx,v,i)=>{
        if (v>mx) {prim=i; return v}
        else if (v==mx) prim=3;
        return mx;
    });
 return colnam[prim];
}
```

`primcol([redval,greenval,blueval])` will return 'r', 'g' or 'b' when one of the colours is dominant, otherwise '-'. Here is a little snippet with sample data:

```js
var cols=[[200,200,30],[23,45,8],[128,240,240],[244,243,242]],colnam="rgb-";

const primcol=c=>{var prim=0;
c.reduce((mx,v,i)=>{
 if (v>mx) {prim=i; return v}
 else if (v==mx) prim=3;
 return mx;
 });
 return colnam[prim];
}
 
cols.forEach(col=>
console.log(col,primcol(col)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I lack reading comprehension I wrote something that should work for any array size which in this case is highly unpractical (especially looking at @TimVN's answer). Nonetheless since the title might lead for people to expect a more general answer consider the following:

```js
let arr = [5,2,2,-4,-3,3,4,-5,-5,3,4,5,5,-7];
    res = Object.entries(arr.reduce((a,c) => {a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1; return a;},{}))
                  .filter(([k,v]) => v == 1)
                  .reduce((m,[k,v]) => m > +k ? m : +k, NaN)

console.log(res);
```

The first inner `reduce` creates an object which we use to store and count the different integers. The idea here is to have a map-like structure instead of nested looping to lower the overall complexity.

From that object we take the entries via `Object.entries` and filter them for a count of `1`. Afterwards we apply `reduce` again to get the highest `key` out of the remaining pairs (those that have a value / count of 1). By setting `NaN` as the reduce start value we establish a way for this function to work even when `filter` returns nothing. `NaN` also helps us in case we want to make this whole thing a boolean.

To make this into a boolean just add `? true : false;` after the `reduce` and you have your evaluation since without a maximum the `reduce` will evaluate to NaN which is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with `r`, `g` and `b`. This way you can compare `colour` with the key names. If it is an array, if `colour = 'r'`, there is no way to map it to the index = 0 and you'd have to check the values manually.

You can loop through the key-value pair and get the max value and `colcheck` based on the condition provided in the question like this:

```js
function getMax(r, g, b, colour) {
  let max = -Infinity,
      colcheck = false,
      map = { r, g, b }

  for (const [k, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
    if(value === max)
      colcheck = false;
    else if (value > max) {
      max = value; // update max value
      colcheck = colour === k;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(max, colcheck)
}

getMax(3, 2, 1, 'r') // unique max and same as colour
getMax(3, 3, 1, 'r') // max same as colour but not unique
getMax(3, 2, 1, 'g') // unique max but not same as colour
```